# Telegram bot alert with input

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

There is an `answerCallbackQuery` that allows you to create an alert reaction on user pressing `InlineKeyboardButton`. Is there any possibility to create simillar alert but with the input field to prompt user to enter some text and send it to bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can't do that with `answerCallbackQuery`, at least for now.

Possible workarounds - send a new `InlineKeyboard` with desired options, or mutate an existing one using `editMessageReplyMarkup`.

Comment: Sadly. Does the only possible way to prompt user to enter something is to use an inline mode?

Comment: For user interaction you can also use [ReplyKeyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) and/or [inline mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode) (inline keyboard != inline mode)